# Keras tuner: what exactly does max_trials, executions_per_trial and epochs do?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I know that all these parameters are in the documentation, but the terminology is confusing. I'm not sure what the difference is between an 'execution' and an 'epoch'. My current understanding is this

- max_trials: the number of combinations of hyper parameters to search over
- executions_per_trial: the number of times to update weights for each combination of hyper parameters
- epochs: the number of times to go through the process of: updating the weights executions_per_trial times for each of the max_trials trials

So using the code below as an example

```
  tuner = RandomSearch(
  hypermodel =  build_model,
  max_trials = 5,
  executions_per_trial = 6,
  hyperparameters = hp,
  objective = 'mse',
  ...
)

tuner %>% fit_tuner(x = x, y = y, 
                    epochs = 100, 
                    validation_data = list(x_val, y_val))
```

I would expect this to update the weights of the model 6 times for 5 combinations of parameters, and do this 100 times. But, like I said, I'm really not sure.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/68336/what-is-max-trials-and-executions-per-trial-in-keras-tuner

Comment: thanks, but I've seen that one already. It says that executions_per_trial is the number of models that should be built and fit for each trial. But why would it build more than one model for each combination of hyperparameters - like what will be the difference between the models if the hyperparameters are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is the following pseudo code:

```
for trial in 1 to max_trials:
    hp = select_hyperparameters()
    for execution in 1 to executions_per_trial:
        model = build_model(hp)
        for epoch in 1 to epochs:
            model.update_weights()
```

For one combination of hyperparameters, you may want to build multiple models if the model you want to evaluate is not deterministic. Indeed, the weights of a neural network are initialized randomly (as well as the order they receive the training data), and two networks with the same architecture will not lead to exactly the same model even if they are trained with the same data. If you train multiple models with the same combination of hyperparameters, you are less likely to observe a case where a good combination led to a bad score, or a bad combination led to a good score.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes things a lot easier to understand. But one follow up question... What exactly are the results of a trial, if there were several executions per trial. I go: `results_summary(tuner, num_trials = 5)` and it shows me one score per trial. Is the score from the best execution or is it an average of all of them, or how can I understand that?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the keras-tuner code, but from the function [`get_best_step`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/98e25d255d53ad56296fdb35327b6201cabaf35e/keras_tuner/engine/tuner_utils.py#L329-L343) that is run at [each trial](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/blob/98e25d255d53ad56296fdb35327b6201cabaf35e/keras_tuner/engine/base_tuner.py#L205) during tuning, I would say that it is the average of all executions.